# TinyMce 4.08 is not working

Tags: tinymce-4

The full featured example mentioned below doesn't seem to work at all when I made the necessary changes to my code. Does anyone encountered the same problem?

Source: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

They say that it's in Beta stage but I was wondering it should at least work.

I'm using TinyMCE 4.0.8 and not the other two. Tried using other two as well, it didn't work.

P.S: I have been using correct path for JavaScript.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Email Interface</title>
<!-- Place inside the <head> of your HTML -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce.min.js"></script>




<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor moxiemanager"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ]
});
</script>  



</head>

<body>
<p>Create an Email Message</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>From address : 
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
</p>
<p>Email Subject : 
  <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" />
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<!--<form method="post">
    <textarea></textarea>
</form> -->


<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</form>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your code, hosted on a server, so we can see what the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you'll see two issues in the full sample:
1- javascript source:

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

2- you need to remove 1 plugin

```
moxiemanager
```

here a working sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/mVKVN/

let me know if you need more details

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it because it's in Beta stage and has bugs? Why does the original code didn't work?

Comment: Not bugs nor Beta, they want to convince you to buy this MoxieManager plugin :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasted lot of hours on this. Just curious, how did you figure out the changes? I trusted what they mentioned on the website. They should not write such things.

Comment: Well, if you open developer tools in chrome or firebug in Firefox, you'll see that there is an error in the plugins. from here you'll be able to find the problematic plugin.

Comment: Buy the way, is it recommended to use `<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>` instead of downloading the package and specifying the js path? I understand that because of jsfiddle you used it but in general, which way is recommended?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39228/discussion-between-tan-and-kdureidy)

Comment: I have been working on tinymce 4 for a while in rails 2,  so what is the solution now for adding images, the way to store/retrieve them? Thank you.